# Unresolveable build extension in Maven

Tags: maven, mule

I am getting below error while building maven project.

```
  [INFO] Scanning for projects...
    Downloading: http://repo.jfrog.org/artifactory/plugins-releases-local/org/jfrog/maven/annomo
    jo/maven-plugin-tools-anno/1.4.0/maven-plugin-tools-anno-1.4.0.pom
    [ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
    [ERROR] Unresolveable build extension: Plugin org.mule.tools.maven:mule-app-maven-plugin:1.0
     or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to collect dependencies at org.mul
    e.tools.maven:mule-app-maven-plugin:jar:1.0 -> org.jfrog.maven.annomojo:maven-plugin-tools-a
    nno:jar:1.4.0 @
    [ERROR] Unknown packaging: mule @ line 6, column 13
     @
    [ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
    [ERROR]
    [ERROR]   The project com.test:testproj:1.0.1 (C:\Users\john\proj\testproj
    c\pom.xml) has 2 errors
    [ERROR]     Unresolveable build extension: Plugin org.mule.tools.maven:mule-app-maven-plugin
    :1.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to collect dependencies at org
    .mule.tools.maven:mule-app-maven-plugin:jar:1.0 -> org.jfrog.maven.annomojo:maven-plugin-too
    ls-anno:jar:1.4.0: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.jfrog.maven.annomojo:maven-plu
    gin-tools-anno:jar:1.4.0: Could not transfer artifact org.jfrog.maven.annomojo:maven-plugin-
    tools-anno:pom:1.4.0 from/to jfrog (http://repo.jfrog.org/artifactory/plugins-releases-local
    ): Connect to repo.jfrog.org:80 [repo.jfrog.org/52.200.110.120, repo.jfrog.org/52.73.83.233]
     failed: Connection refused: connect -> [Help 2]
    [ERROR]     Unknown packaging: mule @ line 6, column 13
    [ERROR]
    [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
    [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
    [ERROR]
    [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the follow
    ing articles:
    [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
    [ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginManagerException
```

Earlier we got connection refused for different IP. we opened the firewall for the same. Now it is showing differnt IP for connection refused. 
Could you please help us on this to reslove the issue?

Comment: Can you share your pom.xml please?

Comment: <repository> <id>mulesoft-ee-proxy</id> <name>Mule Proxy</name> <url>http://hostname:port/nexus/content/repositories/muleee/</url> <layout>default</layout> </repository> <repository> <id>Central</id> <name>Central</name> <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url> <layout>default</layout> </repository> <repository> <id>mulesoft-releases</id> <name>MuleSoft Releases Repository</name> <url>http://repository.mulesoft.org/releases/</url> <layout>default</layout> </repository>

Comment: <repository> <id>mulesoft-snapshots</id> <name>MuleSoft Snapshots Repository</name> <url>http://repository.mulesoft.org/snapshots/</url> <layout>default</layout> </resrepository><pluginRepository>
   <id>mulesoft-release</id>
   <name>mulesoft release repository</name>
   <layout>default</layout>
   <url>http://repository.mulesoft.org/releases/</url>
   <snapshots>
    <enabled>false</enabled>
   </snapshots>

Comment: not able to connect to above rep and plugins . Do we need to open firewall for every host or can we do single operation?

Comment: it's impossible to read code in the comments. Please edit your question and add it there.

Comment: You base problem is this: `Connect to repo.jfrog.org:80 [repo.jfrog.org/52.200.110.120, repo.jfrog.org/52.73.83.233]
     failed: Connection refused: connect`....

Comment: i.e it is not able to connect to the repo.jfrog.org. This could be some firewall issue or anything else?